# DFS-R alternatives?

Tags: windows-server-2008, replication, dfs-r

I was wondering what alternatives to DFS-R are out there on windows machines for **real-time** bidirectional file & folder replication?
DFS-R requires active directory and a domain controller which I don't want utilize in this particular environment.

Thanks!

Tom

Comment: I'm just researching this subject too, so far found following: [**Global Space WAFLS**](http://www.globalscape.co.uk/wide-area-file-services), [**Peer Lock**](http://www.peersoftware.com/products/peerlock/peerlock.aspx) there is also interesting discussion in comments under this article:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/02/20/understanding-the-lack-of-distributed-file-locking-in-dfsr.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [Software Pursuits SureSync](http://www.softwarepursuits.com/suresync/suresync.asp) to keep a production and standby spare file server hosting roughly 2TB of data in sync at one Customer site. I'm using it in a unidirectional capacity but I know that it supports bidirectional sync (and delta compression, and using the NTFS change journal, and a host of other features). There is an [add-on lock manager](http://www.softwarepursuits.com/suresync/add_ons/file_locking.asp) available that, I would suspect you might also need. I've been very happy with the software (we've been using it for roughly 6 years) and, with a couple of issues that the manufacturer addressed, it has been very stable and reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will definitely look at it. Did you ever experience any file corruption, etc.? Also, do you have any experience as to how it compares to DFS-R?

Comment: We use SureSync for replication to a "standby" file server, which is used as the source for tape backups and can have its name / IP swapped with the production file server at a moment's notice. Because we're using only unidirectional replication I would expect the chances to file corruption to be much less than in a bidirectional sync environment. I have no direct comparisons with DFS-R, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I would also say that, depending on your needs, you could try command-line options of Beyond Compare (the Pro / paid version) - supposedly, it can do two-way and/or "mesh synch" (multi-tiered merges of different file locations).

Additionally, please don't forget the old tried-and-true (and free) Robocopy.